# Which Batman comic had the Joker trick a man into thinking he was ugly?

Tags: comics, dc, batman

IIRC there was a Batman comic which featured a storyline in which the Joker manipulated a young man into thinking he was hideously ugly despite his evident good looks with blonde hair and blue eyes.

Can anyone recall which storyline or comic book number it was?

Comment: “despite his evident good looks with blonde hair and blue eyes” — we are lucky like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was [number 50 of the Legends of the Dark Knight](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Legends_of_the_Dark_Knight_Vol_1_50), called "Images", by Dennis O'Neil and Bret Blevins.

In this story the Joker has a cousin called Melvin Reipan, an *idiot savant* with a genius for chemistry and the mind of a child. The Joker tricks him into believing that he is hideous and that they'll find a "cure" for him.

The Joker tests the "joker venom", developed by Melvin, on Melvin's cat. He also uses Melvin's body to feign his own death.

[image: grinning cat, grinning Joker]

This story presents a different version of the first encounter between Batman and the Joker. Batman is able to recall that he heard the Joker's voice before as the Red Hood.

Comment: Fantastic - I think it was indeed.  The panels available online look exactly like the story I am referring to.  Thank you indeed.